# Access Class Variable on general Object of that class

Tags: java, class, object, reflection

I have a lots of classes for example this one:

```
public class DepartmentST {
    public Long id = null;
    public String name = null;
    public String comments = null;
    public Long[] profiles = null;
    public Boolean default_val = false;
}
```

In main class I create objects of those classes and sent it to general method for example:

```
DepartmentST mydepartment = new DepartmentST();
generalMethod(mydepartment);
```

In general Method I want to access to object fields (this my question how?)

```
public generalMethod(Object myObj) {
    Field[] fields = myObj.getClass().getFields();
    for(Field field : fields) {
        String fieldName = field.getName();
        // I want to access that field how can i tell myObj.fielName ?
    }
}
```

I'm new in Java I don't know it's stupid question or not.

thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reflection generic get field value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400075/reflection-generic-get-field-value)

Comment: You mean like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#setInt(java.lang.Object, int)

Comment: It looks like a design smell to me. Why doesn't the method take a DepartmentST  as argument? Or at least a reference to a superclass or interface common to all objects? What should this general method do? Why are you using public fields?

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran it was mistake its myObj

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza you mean I can access it by field.get(myObj)?

Comment: Yes, as simple as that...

Comment: This is a good example of misusing reflection. You should better define a base class or a common interface.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks it works :) how can I thank you and mark as answer your comment?

Comment: It is not my answer, it is a duplicate Q/A. I never posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get(java.lang.Object)

```
public generalMethod(Object myObj) {
    Field[] fields = myObj.getClass().getFields();
    for(Field field : fields) {
        String fieldName = field.getName();
        // I want to access that field how can i tell myObj.fielName ?

        Class c = field.getType();
        if (c instanceOf Integer) {
            Integer value = field.getInt (myObj);
        }

        // or

        Object value = field.get (myObj); 

    }
}
```

Comment: I've just read your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141582/access-class-variable-on-general-object-of-that-class#comment33596804_22141615) and want to tell you my full ack ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You need to "cast" the object to a DepartmentST object:

```
if (myObj instanceof DepartmentST) {
    DepartmentST department = (DepartmentST) myObj;
    // continue with code
```

Then use that object instead of myObj.

Comment: And do an `instanceof` check before.

Comment: there are a lot of classes, How can I tell this is DepartmentST or ProfileST?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The OP doesn't say he wants to use reflection! He wants to access the member variable. And this answer shows how to do it better without reflection.

Comment: @user714965 did you at least read the code? If you did, do you know about reflection classes like `Class` and `Field`?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I guess he doesn't know better

Comment: @MohseTaheri you can tell this by the `instanceof` check. See the edited answer.

Comment: ppl don't usually jump in and use reflection unless there is a need.

Comment: When using reflection you have the advantage to **not need** to know which class are you working with directly, the code will work for every object reference (even object references from `Object`!). So, this code may be used for lot of classes, you surely don't want to have lot of `if (myObj instanceof Foo) { ... } else if (myObj instanceof Bar) { ... } ... ` and on...

Comment: By the way, just read OP's code and the possible duplicate Q/A to understand how to solve this problem with 1 line of code...

Answer (score -1):

Basically this code breaks the encapsulation. You need private fields, and you access them through getters and setters. Reflection is another way to go (depending on the context).