# What is supposed to be passed into this method (Field#get(Object obj))?

Tags: java, oracle, reflection, field

After looking at the Java documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html), and reading an [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html), as well as visiting [this question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400075/reflection-generic-get-field-value), I am still dumbfounded as to what the `Object` argument in `Field#get(Object obj)` actually is.

The process that I take to get a field using Reflection is:

```
Field field = SomeClass.getClass().getDeclaredField("someField");
field.setAccessible(true);
```

Which gives the `Field` object. Now, to get the actual value of the field, you would use the `Field#get(Object obj)` method. The documentation for this method says the following about the parameter.

> obj - object from which the represented field's value is to be extracted

I have no idea what the description of the parameter even means. Can someone explain to me what this argument is truly asking for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have a class `Foo`:

```
public class Foo {
    public int bar;
}
```

Now you can have multiple instances of this class:

```
Foo f1 = new Foo();
f1.bar = 1;
Foo f2 = new Foo();
f2.bar = 2;
```

To get the value of the field `bar` of `f1` reflectively, you would call

```
field.get(f1); // returns 1
```

To get the value of the field `bar` of `f2` reflectively, you would call

```
field.get(f2); // returns 2
```

Comment: Ah! So much clearer. Thanks, this makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
public class TestReflect
{
  private int value;

  public static void main ( String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException
  {
    Field field = TestReflect.class.getDeclaredField("value");

    TestReflect objRed = new TestReflect();
    TestReflect objBlue = new TestReflect();

    objRed.value = 1;
    objBlue.value = 2;

    System.out.println( field.get(objRed) );
    System.out.println( field.get(objBlue) );
  }
}
```

You will get as output :

```
1
2
```

There the `field` variable is referencing the variable `value` from the class `TestReflect`. But `value` is an [instance variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_variable) so each and every object of class `TestReflect` has its own `value` variable. To get the `value` variable you need to specify from which object you are getting it and that is what the parameter is for.