# Fetching associated entities with AuditQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, audit, hibernate-envers

For example I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(....
public class Worker
{
    private Long id;
    private String name ;
}

@Entity
@Audited
@Table(....
public class Department
{
    private Long id;
    private String departmentName;
    private Worker worker;

}
```

I want to display the following data for `Department`:

| `departmentName` | `name` (from fetched entity`worker`) |

When using `AuditQuery` to get audit information for entity `Department`, is it possible to fetch the entity `Worker` to display `name` value for more human readable display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not supported, so you'll have to use a native query and join the actual database tables.

Comment: I solved my problem by initializing proxies using java reflection.

Comment: You can also add the answer here, maybe it will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

`EAGER` loading is not supported by envers, all association can only be lazy loaded. An alternative solution to doing joins by hand, is initializing lazy fields of an entity.

My solution to this problem was to go through all fields using java reflection ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400075/reflection-generic-get-field-value)), finding proxies by using [Hibernate.isInitialized(...)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#isInitialized%28java.lang.Object%29) and initializing them with [Hibernate.initialize(...)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#initialize%28java.lang.Object%29).