# loop through field's values (or methods) of an object in java

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class called `Material` and some subclasses of it: `Book, Audio, magazine`... 
I also have an `ArrayList<Material> arrayOfMaterials`

I am trying to implement a search method: I want to give a string to this method as a parameter and it should call all the `getters()` in every object inside the array, plus the `toString` functions and compare the results to the input parameter.

I have read about Reflection in java, but if I got it right, that will give me the names of the fields or methods of a class, but won't give me the values of those fields in objects or the results of calling its `getters()`.

I need to loop through ALL getters, or through all fields (I shouldn't access fields from outside, but it'd work), and not all subclasses of `Material`have the same number of fields.

Is there any way to do this? I have no code to paste because, as far as I know, there is no way to do this.

Comment: Reflection will give you values: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400075/reflection-generic-get-field-value

Comment: Can't you write the method get for the class Material? so all subclasses can inherit it.

Comment: @Niles Does It make sense that a subclass inherits a getter for a field it doesn't have? Anyway, if I get to loop, I don't think the number of cycles will be a big deal. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidVV if your superclass have a field also all subclasses have that field, at least you have to be careful to don't override it.
You can of course insert the *get* into your loop.

Comment: @Niles but if I put the books specific fields or getters inside the superclass, all subclasses will inherit those fields o getters. I don't think I want that

Comment: @DavidVV if you have a different getter for each classe you can also use **istance of**, it is not so elegant but works... By the way... if you still have your problem explain it better, I will try to help you.

Comment: As far as I understand you are doing some kind of search based on the string parameter you pass. You can create an abstract method in `Material` like `abstract boolean contains(String property)` and then have each of your subclass implement it. Reflection API is not there to replace OOP principles.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak that is actually a lot better and easier! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example retrieves the field names of the concrete class (declaredField = fields declared by the class, (public)field = public fields declared by the class and it's super classes), derives a name of a corresponding getter from it (i.e. `private String example` ->  `getExample`), searches for the method with the same name and invokes it on the instance `m` of `Material`

```
Material m = ...;
Stream.of(Material.class.getDeclaredFields())
      .map(field -> "get" + ucFirst(field.getName()))
      .map(getterName -> Material.class.getMethod(getterName))
      .map(getterMethod -> getterMethod.invoke(m))
      .forEach(fieldValue -> {
            //do something
      });

...
private String ucFirst(String input) {
    if(input.length() <= 1){
        return input.toUpperCase();
    }
    return input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);
}
```

(I removed the exception handling for better readability)

This is just *one* way to do it, there are many others. The same way you could access the `toString` method:

```
String toString = (String)Material.class.getMethod("toString").invoke(m);
```

Or you could get all the getter you want:

```
Stream.of(Material.class.getMethods())
      .filter(method -> method.getName().startsWith("get"))
      .map(getterMethod -> getterMethod.invoke(m))
      .forEach(fieldValue -> {
            //do something
      });
```

Note that `getMethods` will retrieve only public methods, but from all the super classes as well, while `getDeclaredMethods` will retrieve only method from the current classes. This may be important to know when dealing with the subclasses.