# How to iterate Field of type List using java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class called User which is having List of Account class objects like this

```
 public class User{
   private List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
 }
```

The Account object is having one transient field which i want to find and do some thing with that

```
public class Account{
  private transient openDateInOrgDateFormat;
}
```

This field i want to find using reflection and then check whether its transient then  do something. Through reflection how to find field of type collection and then iterate that and to find if field inside the object which is in the list is transient or not.

Comment: Check the [java reflection trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldModifiers.html), they've even got an example that suit your needs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reflection generic get field value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400075/reflection-generic-get-field-value)

Comment: Your question from title asks specifically from List, but later you are asking for "field of type collection". So which is it, List or any Collection like List, Set, other? Also what exactly is stopping you from writing your code? Which step you have problem with?

Comment: `(field.getModifiers() && Modifier.TRANSIENT) != 0` to check that field is transient.

Comment: @talex `Modifier.isTransient(field.getModifiers())` is probably easier to read.

Comment: @talex And it's `&` not `&&`.

Comment: @Kayaman yes. you right.

Comment: @Pschemo I am looking to iterate Account objects list inside User using reflection and then check transient inside Account object.

Comment: OK, but in that comment you still didn't explain what is stopping you from dong so. From my answer you know how to get that list from `User` object, so iterate over its elements. Check properties you want and do with them what you want. If you need help with specific *problem* you need to describe it. Don't confuse *requirements* with *problem description*, these are separate things. Requirements specify what you want, problem description specifies what is stopping you from achieving your goal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since I don't know what exactly is stopping you from writing your code here are some tools which should be helpful:

- to get array of fields declared in class use

  ```
  Field[] fields = User.class.getDeclaredFields()
  ```
- to check what is the type assigned to field use `field.getType()`.
- to check if type is same as other type like List simply use

  ```
  type.equals(List.class);
  ```
- to check if one type belongs to family of some ancestor (like List is subtype of Collection) use `isAssignableFrom` like

  ```
  Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(List.class)
  ```
- to check modifiers of field like `transient` use

  ```
  Modifier.isTransient(field.getModifiers())
  ```
- to access *value* held by field in specific instance, use

  ```
  Object value = field.get(instanceWithThatField)
  ```

  but in case of `private` fields you will need to make it accessible first via `field.setAccessible(true)`. Then if you are sure about what type of object `value` holds you can cast it to that type like

  ```
  List<Account> list = (List<Account>) value;
  ```

  or do both operations in one line, like in your case

  ```
  List<Account> list = (List<Account>) field.get(userObject);
  ```

  which you can later iterate the way you want like
  `for(Account acc : list){ /*handle each acc*/ }`

Comment: Basically my question is if Field is of type list then how to typecast Field to Collection and iterate using reflection.

Comment: @PracheerPancholi you don't typecast field to collection. You need to get value of field held in some `User` object. So like mentioned in last point, you need to use `field.setAccessible(true); Object value = field.get(userObject);`. Then you can try casting `value` to `Collection` or other type which is accurate for object held by `value` reference.

Comment: thanks this answers my question.Please modify the answer so that I can accept that.

Comment: @PracheerPancholi Check if that is what you meant.

Comment: how to get the object of user class means you have mentioned        `field.get(userObject)` in this how to get userObject

Comment: @PracheerPancholi In your example `User` holds `List<Account> accounts`, but different users will hold different accounts. So when we write something like `user1.getAccouts()` we will get different list than one returned via `user2.getAccounts()`. `Field` is not bounded with any specific instance, but it represents part of class structure. So if you want to use that `Field` object you need to tell it from which user it should read it and return it. So if you want to get accounts from user1 like `user1.getAccounts()` you need `accountsField.get(user1)` (where `accountsField` is `Field`).

Comment: @PracheerPancholi Answer of "how to get the object of user class" depends on your application. I am assuming you already have these users somewhere and you simply need to pass them to your method which is using reflection. If you don't have any users, then you may need to create them and fill with data, but then why would you need reflection if you already have this user class so you can write your code without it.

Comment: the whole idea is to exclude transient field in json request using ExclusionStrategy shouldSkipField method overriding. The `shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes fa)` has to be overriden for that i am doing. In that i am doing this `Class<User> declaredClass = (Class<User>) fa.getDeclaringClass() ` and then doing `Field[] declaredFields = declaredClass.getDeclaredFields();` and then i am checking ` if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType()))` and now  in this case i have list of Account object and what i need is to iterate that and ignore  transient field inside that.

Comment: I don't have userObject as such so how to get that and iterate list elements so that i can find out transient field in Account object and then ignore that field in json request.

Comment: @PracheerPancholi Sorry, but I am not familiar with ExclusionStrategy shouldSkipField so I am afraid I will not be able to help you. Consider creating separate question in which you will explain what you want to achieve and what problem you are facing. But honestly, something tells me that you may may be trying to recreate a wheel. From what I remember Gson (I am assuming that is your library) is already skipping any transient fields - if I understood your intentions correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on @Pshemo's answer, Here are the steps:
(Please note its easier to get specific Type parameters from a Class than an Object, due to Type erasures.)

1. Loop through the fields in User.
2. For fields with predefined types
   check transcience.
3. For Collections, get the type of of its parameter
   and if its a custom Type, run a recursion on that class.

e.g

```
    private static void checkTranscience(Class<?> clazz) {
    for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println("Transience " + Modifier.isTransient(field.getModifiers()) + " for " + field.getName());
        Class<?> fieldClass;
        if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
            //In case of Parameterized List or Set Field, extract genericClassType
            fieldClass = (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        } else {
            fieldClass = field.getType();
        }
        //Assuming Account belongs to "com.examplepackage.accountpackage" package to narrow down recursives to custom Types only
        if (fieldClass.getName().contains("com.examplepackage.accountpackage")) {
            checkTranscience(fieldClass);
        }
    }


class User {
    private String x;
    private List<String> stringList;
    private List<Account> accounts;
    private int y;
}

public static void main(){
    checkTranscience(User.class);
}
```

You might have to tune the code a bit to get the specific result, but I'll leave that to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with arrays stream:

```
Object obj;
Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
List<Field> fieldOfTypeList =  Arrays.stream(fields).distinct().filter(field -> field.getType().equals(List.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```