# Getting static fields values of Build class

Tags: java, android, build, static

There is `Build.SERIAL` static field for instance. Is there another way to get this value rather than just reading it from static field?

Comment: But is it not easy to read this way?

Comment: For those who don't know any other way (like me), explaining the reason behind it could help us understand the problem and provide other solutions.

Comment: @7383 it's easy, I just wan't to understand if there is any other way.

Comment: @JonZarate there're lots of libraries which could use `Build` values. I'm interested if I change Build values with reflection which values libraries can  receive.

Comment: how about reflection? perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13401094/794088

Comment: So you need private data, why do you need it from `Build`? Store it in a database, web server etc. and read it from there. Why do you need such an id from the phone?

Comment: According to [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26572/changing-android-os-build-serial) answer, I believe root user can read it from the file itself.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this can work. Only reason why someone would use it, I can think of `private static field`, witch can be accessed only form class where it is declared. You can get access from another class through getter method.

```
private static String abcd = "ABCD";

public String getAbcd(){
  return this.abcd;
}
```