# Java - Return sum for specific attribute of List<Object>

Tags: java

Let's assume I have the following class:

```
class Transaction{
  Float amount;
  String Id;
}
```

Now I'd like to implement a function:

```
public static Float sum(List<Object> list, String attribute)
```

That returns the sum of all objects in the list for the specified attribute.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at [Reflection get field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400075/reflection-generic-get-field-value), and then it's like everytime you're summing up

Comment: The answer for most cases is _you shouldn't_. Instead, you should not fight the Java type system and instead use generics and `Function`.

Comment: If you really need to pass the attribute as a String then you must use reflection. A better way is to pass a Function to map the Transaction to the attribute needed.

Comment: What do you mean by specified attribute? You cannot sum `Id` to a float.

Answer (score 1):

Such function you are asking can only be implemented using reflection. This should work:

```
public static Float sum(List<Object> list, String attribute) {

    Float sum = 0f;

    for (Object object : list) {
        Class<?> c = object.getClass();
        try {
            Field field = c.getDeclaredField(attribute);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            sum += (Float) field.get(object);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

But it might be a bad practice. It is very likely that someone would use this method in a bad way resulting in a exception being thrown. Consider other options better than java reflection.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was searching for.

Comment: You are welcome @DieterKrause! Please accept the best answer so people keep answering

Answer (score 0):

Use Java 8 Streams

since your question is too vague. this might help.

Assuming you have a List of transactions where id is the specified attribute. You create a stream of transactions, then filter(`filter`) using the specified attribute. After filtering convert the stream to double(`mapToDouble`) then finally sum them(`sum`).

You can achieve a similar result using forLoops.

```
class Transaction {
Float amount;
String id;

public Transaction(Float amount, String id) {
    this.amount = amount;
    this.id = id;
}

public Float getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(Float amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}

class Summation {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final double one = summingFunction("one");
    System.out.println(one);
 }

public static double summingFunction(String filter){
  return  Stream.of(new Transaction(10.20F, "one"), new Transaction(11.11F,"one"), new Transaction(10F, "two"))
            .filter(transaction -> transaction.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(filter))
            .mapToDouble(Transaction::getAmount).sum();
   }
  }
```